# Security concerns of using hidden fields for post edits

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have a page for editing posts. Let's say the user goes to site.dev/post/edit/104 to get a form populated with all data for that post from the database.

I store the post id in a hidden field so it's easier to access for some ajax components I have on the page.

Now, I can just open up FireBug and alter the post id in the hidden field no problem. What's to stop a malicious user from making a simple script that just changes the post id and and overwrites every post id in the database with whatever they filled out in that form?

Granted, the user does have to be authenticated to access the page, and I do validate on the server side to make sure the post ID and other fields are holding acceptable values, but as long as the post id is an integer, it will update them all. I suppose this is still an issue with it being passed by query strings in the URL, but then the page at least loads all the content.

I'm a little confused on this and I can't really think of a more 'secure' alternative to this right now. Is there some way to prevent this?

I am building with Codeigniter if there are any suggestions related specifically to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make your variables more secure you can use the CI's Encryption Class. You just have to set an encryption key in your config file, load the library in your controller & encrypt the ID with the following code:

```
$id = 1;
$encrypted_id = $this->encrypt->encode($id);
```

So, when you print the URL, instead of printing directly the id as an integer, print the encrypted_id. The user will have no idea of what this means and, as long as it doesn't have your key, it can't decode the id :D

When you receive the encoded id, you can decode it by using the decode() method of the encryption class.

For more information visit:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about an administrator-page, then there's no real security-issue, if the administrator wants to change any post, he/she can just do that anyway.

If it's a user-page, where a user can change his/her own posts, then you can simply check if it is the authenticated user that made the post in the first place.

Core principle; have a way to check which user sent the request at all times, and the rest is up to your receiving script to validate. And for that, you cannot trust the user to truthfully saying who he/she is (i.e. you cannot save the user-id in a hidden post-field, so make use of session-ids or similar if you use ajax for the request).

Answer (score 0):

In general user input cannot be trusted. There is no mechanism that can prevent the user from altering what gets sent to the server. All the data has to be validated for every single request. In this case, it means checking that the post id is valid and that the user has the right to edit it. As long as you perform these checks it really doesn't matter if the user send hand-crafted requests as there is nothing he could do that he couldn't by using your site normally.

Of course it means that you need a way to identify which user sent a particular request. If you use a session id for that purpose you must make sure that they are generated randomly so that the user cannot guess a valid id belonging to a different user.